# Deleting conversation between two users from QucikBlox history in iOS

Tags: ios

I am using Qucik Blox SDK for chatting in iOS app. I need to delete conversation between two users (e.g David & John having conversation of total 200 messages). So I need to delete conversation between David & John??

Please suggest how I can do this??

Comment: Like this : http://quickblox.com/developers/Chat#Delete_message

Comment: No i need to delete all 200 messages in single attempt.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible to delete an entire 1-1 chat dialog. Just review their documentation. Always a good place to start :)

http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#Delete_dialog